# Room and RxJava Providing Inconsistent Results

Tags: rx-java2, android-room

This is my first time working with Room and RxJava. I'm getting some very inconsistent results when I'm reading from the DB. I have a nested RecyclerView, where the first simply shows the days of the week and the second shows the forecast for each day.

Sometimes when I launch the app, everything shows up right away. Other times, only the days will be shown, but not the forecast for each day. Other times, neither RecyclerViews are shown. However, if I view the DB using Stetho, the data is there within the device.

Here's how I've setup my Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {

    // Other CRUD methods

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT date FROM my_table")
    Single<List<LocalDate>> getUniqueDays();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date == :localDate")
    Single<List<Forecasts>> getForecastForDay(LocalDate localDate);

}
```

I populate the first RecyclerView using the following:

```
Single<List<LocalDate>> source = MyApp.getDatabase().getDao().getUniqueDays();
source.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<LocalDate>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<LocalDate> localDates) {
                mAdapter.refreshData(localDates);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }
        });
```

This is called within a fragment that displays the days of the week.

Then, within the adapter for the days of the week, I also need to populate the inner RecyclerView, which is done within my `bind()` of the ViewHolder:

```
public void bind(LocalDate date, int position){

   // A bunch of other views being set


    mHourlyForecasts.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mHourlyForecasts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mAdapter = new HourlyForecastAdapter(mContext);
    mHourlyForecasts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Single<List<Forecasts>> source = MyApp.getDatabase().getDao().getForecastForDay(date);
    source.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Forecasts>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Forecasts> conditions) {
                    Timber.i("Size of conditions in onSuccess(): %d", conditions.size());
                    mAdapter.refreshData(conditions);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });
}
```

However, I have no idea as to why the data isn't being shown consistently. Sometimes at startup the data isn't shown, sometimes it is. Sometimes I'll close out the app and re-open it and some data is missing. Or all of it is there. And again, the data is there in the DB when I inspect the device in Stetho, it's just not being shown within the RecyclerView(s).

If anyone can provide some guidance on this, it would be immensely appreciated...

Comment: Try inserting a subscription delay (`delaySubscription(5, SECONDS)`) into those queries and see if you get all data. I don't know Room in detail, but maybe it is slow to initialize itself, the queries find empty in-memory tables and just return immediately.

Comment: There are multiple oddities with this code. 1.) using `Single` instead of `Flowable`/`Observable` disables you from getting updates made to your data. 2.) You could use `DisposableObserver` so that you receive a `Disposable` with `subscribeWith` and then you can dispose the disposable when you're binding a new subscription. You might also want to dispose (and re-initialize) the subscription in `onViewDetachedFromWindow` and `onViewAttachedToWindow` respectively 3.) you probably don't need to re-initialize the layoutmanager and the adapter each time.

Comment: @akarnokd that seems to have done the trick for the time being. Thanks for the input, appreciate all of the help!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you're very right about using a `Flowable` instead of a `Single`. I've tried switching things over to `Flowable`, but I'm now getting a lot of jank in my app. I will post another question on SO to see what I'm doing wrong.... Appreciate all of your help on this.